# Despite the long search and the use of many solutions, I cannot implement this code

Tags: android, arrays, android-mediaplayer

I have a sound in an array with three buttons. I want to write a
correct code to play the sounds correctly. Search When I press the
play button, the sound in the same element in the array is turned on,
while the code actually turns on the sound, but when I press another
element, the sound does not stop. The former works all the sounds,
which causes inconvenience, as well as the rest of the buttons. I
want them to work in the same manner in pausing and stopping
permanently. These are the codes for sound playback. Please explain
the error in it and correct it
**Thank you**
....

```
package com.example.android.quran;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

//public class customadapter extends BaseAdapter {
public class customadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int resourse;
    MediaPlayer mdp ;
    ImageView play, pause,stop;
    private boolean flage = true;
   private ArrayList<com.example.android.quran.quran> quran;
    public customadapter (Context context, int resourse, ArrayList<com.example.android.quran.quran> quran){
this.context= context;
this.resourse= resourse;
this.quran= quran;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return quran.size();
    }
    public quran getitem(int i){
        return quran.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View e = view;
        if (e==null) {
            e=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resourse, null, false);
        }
        TextView soraname = e.findViewById(R.id.text_sora);
        TextView soranumber = e.findViewById(R.id.text_sora_num);
       play =e.findViewById(R.id.img_play);
       pause =e.findViewById(R.id.img_pause);
       stop =e.findViewById(R.id.img_stop);
        final quran d = getitem(i);
        soraname.setText(d.getName());
        soranumber.setText(d.getNumber());
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mdp==null) {
                mdp =MediaPlayer.create(context,d.getsound());
                mdp.start();

                }else {
                    mdp.start();
                    mdp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            stop_play();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mdp.isPlaying()) {
                    mdp.pause();
                }else {
                    mdp.start();
                }
            }
        });
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mdp.isPlaying()) {
                    stop_play();
                }
            }
        });
        return e;
    }
    public void stop_play(){
        if (mdp!=null){
            mdp.stop();
            mdp.release();
            mdp = null;
        }
    }


}
   ....
```

Comment: _"when I press another element, the sound does not stop."_ Maybe try calling `stop()` on the `MediaPlayer` instance before creating a new one and calling `play()`(?)

Comment: thank you
The truth is that the shapes in the pause button with playback because when you press the pause button, it actually pauses, but if you press the play button for another element, it completes the item that was previously paused, so I want to solve this problem
NB
The stop button works fine. If you press it and then press another item, this item will work without problems